# Получение данных из таблицы django

Tags: python, django

**Модель**

```
    from django.db import models
from .category import Category
import datetime

class Products(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Название товара")
    category_name = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1, verbose_name="Категория")
    description = models.TextField(max_length=2200, default='' , null=True , blank=True, verbose_name="Описание")
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/products/', verbose_name="Главное")
    articul = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="", verbose_name="Артикул")
    date_of_start = models.DateField(default=datetime.datetime.today, verbose_name="Дата")
    color = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="", verbose_name="Цвет")
    price = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="", verbose_name="Цена")
    # photos = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/products/'б verbose_name="Главное")

    status_choiche = (
        ('В наличии', 'В наличии'),
        ('Под заказ', 'Под заказ'),
        ('Распродажа', 'Распродажа'),
    )

    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=status_choiche, default='В наличии', verbose_name="Статус")

    class Images(models.Model):
        product = models.ForeignKey('Products', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/products/%Y/%m/%d')
        
        def get_absolute_image_url(self):
            return os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_URL, self.images.url)

    @staticmethod
    def get_products_by_id(ids):
        return Products.objects.filter(id__in =ids)

    @staticmethod
    def get_all_products():
        return Products.objects.all()

    @staticmethod
    def get_all_products_by_categoryid(category_name_id):
        if category_name_id:
            return Products.objects.filter(category_name = category_name_id)
        else:
            return Products.get_all_products();


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Продукт'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Продукты'
```

**admin.py**

```
class VideoDetailsInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Products.Images
class VideoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [VideoDetailsInline]
class VideoDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Products.Images
        fields = '__all__'
class VideoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Products
        fields = '__all__'
```

**view detail**

```
from store.models.products import Products, Images

def store_detail(request, product_id):
    productdetail = Products.objects.get(id = product_id) 

    # id ссылки
    field_object = Products._meta.get_field('category_name_id')
    category_name_id = getattr(productdetail, field_object.attname)
    category = Category.objects.all()
    # Получение названия категории имея ее id
    category_name = Category.objects.get(id = category_name_id)
    
    images = Products.objects.get(id = 25).Images.id

    data = {
    'productdetail': productdetail,
    'category_name_id': category_name_id,
    'category_name': category_name,
    'category': category,
    'images': images
    }

    return render(request, 'product_detail.html', data)

    return render(request, 'product_detail.html', data)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне вывести данные из таблицы в html? (см. изображение)

```
ImportError at /store/25
cannot import name 'Images' from 'store.models.products' (/home/django/django_venv/src/store/models/products.py)
Request Method: GET
Django Version: 3.2.2
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
cannot import name 'Images' from 'store.models.products' (/home/django/django_venv/src/store/models/products.py)
Exception Location: /home/django/django_venv/src/store/views/home.py, line 4, in <module>
Python Executable:  /home/django/django_venv/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.8.5
Python Path:    
['/home/django/django_venv/src',
 '/home/django/django_venv/bin',
 '/usr/lib/python38.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '/home/django/django_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 28 Jul 2021 18:29:48 +0300
```

Comment: Вот так `{% for image in images %}id: {{ image.id }} / image: {{ image.image.name }} / product_id: {{ image.product_id }}{% endfor %}`

Comment: Как описать переменную image во views.py?

Comment: Её не нужно описывать в views.py

Comment: Пробывал images = Products.objects.get(id = product_id).Images.image, но пишет что нельзя импортировать Images

Comment: Не нужно ничего делать, у вас уже есть `images = Images.objects.all()`

Comment: В таком случае будет ошибка `name 'Images' is not defined`, а если попытаться импортировать будет ошибка `name 'Images' is not defined`

Comment: `from store.models import Images` очевидно. Вам нужно изучить основы питона

Comment: если попытаться импортировать будет ошибка name 'Images' is not defined

Comment: Покажите полный текст ошибки и полный код файла вместе с импортом

Comment: `cannot import name 'Images' from 'store.models.products' (/home/django/django_venv/src/store/models/products.py)`

Comment: Обновил вопрос, там добавил

Comment: Покажите содержимое файла store/models/products.py с корректно расставленными отступами, а не как сейчас в тексте вопроса

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Ну, если верить показанным отступам — у вас одна модель находится внутри другой модели, поэтому и не импортируется. В модели `Images` уберите отступ на одну табуляцию влево

Comment: И вообще переместите её вниз под модель Products, не надо смешивать модели внутри друг друга

Comment: Дело не в табуляции, я бы не смог мигрировать модель (https://yapx.ru/v/NYLTL)

Comment: Нет, дело именно в табуляции, так делать нельзя и в учебниках Django ничего такого не написано. Если вы не можете мигрировать модель без этой табуляции, значит у вас какая-то другая ошибка (и вам всё ещё нужно изучить основы питона)